# how to use main c++ program to build a sound related library (without using any third party library)

Tags: c++, native, speech-recognition, computer-science

I have no idea about native programing with c++. I am new on programing world. I have a question how to build a library without any third party library. For example developer of `Carnegie Mellon University` developed a speech RECOGNITION Library. How did they develop it. What things they use for. Isn't they use any third party library? Is it possible to make a library using only main programing language and its original library. I want to learn how to use only c++ and its library to develop a sound related library.

I am so young and am not a student of any computer science university. And also don't know how to ask a good question. Please forgive me if i made any mistake.

Thanks to all.

Comment: For which platform would you like to develop it?

Comment: i am beginner. C++ is my first choice. on Windows

Comment: Can i code for multiplatform?

Comment: You can. However, I would advice starting out with one platform first if you want to do low level audio programming.

Comment: Thanks #Michiel Pater

Comment: If you would like to code for multi-platform, you might want to check out the JUCE library: https://www.juce.com/  Cross-platform and audio dev are what it specializes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the waveOut API from Microsoft:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743866(v=vs.85).aspx

This is a tutorial:

https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4422&lngWId=3

I wrote a basic Audio Engine myself using this API which features 3D Audio, echo, looping, custom frequency, etc.

The waveOut API is quite low level.